# CakePHP: Reusable Actions in controller

Tags: cakephp, controller, components, action, cakephp-2.3

Suppose I have multiple controllers for different models (like posts, photos etc.) Each controller has an action `admin_init` which does the same things in all models. What is the easiest and cleanest way to "outsorce" these actions into a plugin?

I have already created a plugin named `Backend` and each said controller uses the component `Backend.Editable`. But what now? How do I add the action and view to each of the controllers?

Comment: the easiest way is to put the action into AppController class. I don't think it's the cleanest so I don't post this as an answer but just as a comment

Comment: I thought so to, but how do I outsource this into a Plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/crud then.
It does the very same thing in a DRY way.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: That plugin IS the answer. I did not want to copy and paste the readme, though.